# How to click a delete icon in a website using imacro

Tags: xpath, imacros

I trying to automate a button click on a website using imacro, here I'm using Xpath to select the button,

TAG XPATH="//*[@class='thumbActBar']/a"

It is just selecting the correct button but doesn't click it,

If i record the imacro i get this,

FRAME NAME="uploader_iframe"
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:del&&ARIA-LABEL:delete&&TABINDEX:0&&ROLE:button&&KP:1&&TXT:

but when it playing it doesn't work

can anybody help me with this issue.....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Event mode will be helpful to you:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="[class='thumbActBar']>a"
```

If you use 'iMacros for Firefox', try the Event mode with your XPath:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK XPATH="//*[@class='thumbActBar']/a"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it's not working, it gives the error "value.trim is not a function, line: 5 (Error code: -1001)"